# System properties management

Tags: jenkins

Is there any "adequate" way to change system properties in Jenkins? What is the easiest/fastest way change them? For instance, I need to turn off the useless (in my case) pinging thread.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you really want a quick and simple way to change a system property, you can use the [script console](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console)

```
System.setProperty("hudson.remoting.Launcher.pingIntervalSec", 0)
```

But that won't survive a restart.  To make it permanent, add the setting to the java args.  For me (CentOS, Jenkins 2.7.1) that's a line about halfway down `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` (for other distributions I believe it's `/etc/default/jenkins`) where you should add your option to the existing list like this:

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.remoting.Launcher.pingIntervalSec=0"
```

You'll have to restart Jenkins after you make that change (thanks Mark Tickner)

Comment: Updating the JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS worked for me, but I had to reboot the server before it took effect

Comment: Using System.setProperty doesn't seem to work, at least not for hudson.slaves.WorkspaceList. I set it to "+" and System.getProperty verifies this but it still uses the default value "@".

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't have sysconfig folder under /etc, how to fix it ?

Comment: @vikramvi I believe it's /etc/default for non-RedHat distributions.  Answer updated.

Comment: On Debian / Ubuntu based Linux distributions you should use `JAVA_ARGS`.

Comment: On Debian, see also /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service (shown in output from /usr/sbin/service jenkins status)

Comment: Since 2.332.1, Jenkins on Linux uses systemd to manage services. As a consequence, system properties should no longer be managed via /etc/default/jenkins or /etc/sysconfig/jenkins but via systemd unit files. See the official documentation for more details on this: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/systemd-services/

Comment: Where can i find "/etc/default/jenkins"?

Answer (score 15):

If you run Jenkins on windows as a service without tomcat, you can edit `jenkins.xml`. Add the property in `<service><arguments>` before the `-jar`. 
Than restart the service.

```
<service>
    <!-- ... -->
    <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m  -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle  -Dhudson.tasks.MailSender.SEND_TO_UNKNOWN_USERS=true  -Dhudson.tasks.MailSender.SEND_TO_USERS_WITHOUT_READ=true  -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
```

Answer (score 5):

The system properties available and how to set them are listed on the wiki:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties

To disable slave pinging, you can set `hudson.remoting.Launcher.pingIntervalSec` to `0`.

System properties can be set in the same way as with any other Java program, e.g.:
`java -Dhudson.remoting.Launcher.pingIntervalSec=0 -jar jenkins.war`

Answer (score 3):

If you use Tomcat on Windows you can edit the File `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.67\conf\catalina.properties` and simply add the Line

`hudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true`

at the End of the File. Then safe the File and restart Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar problem: I need to disable DNSMultiCast (set hudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled = false) and I can't understand how to do it

for example, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties  - there is such advice  "...pass all of these arguments before the -jar argument..." but I run jenkins under tomcat so I am not sure I can change startup parameters.

I tried to change /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/jenkins.xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context >
 <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="/var/jenkins"
         type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
 <Environment name="hudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled" value="true"
         type="java.lang.Boolean" override="false"/>
</Context>
```

but I didn't help. 
Can someone explain how to change jenkins system properties when tomcat is used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719756/how-to-stop-jenkins-log-from-becoming-huge take a look at this. You may also ask the author how and where did he put this java setting and compare to your Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a bad hack but I set it in the pipeline job that needs the setting.
Like this:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")  // allow formatted HTML pages to be published
```

It seems to work - as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 1):

I followed each steps mentioned above but it fails.

So I did change the system time zone using ***`timedatectl set-timezone Europe/London`*** command and then I have restarted jenkins service ***`service jenkins restart`*** it worked.

1. I was using Rehdat 7.5
2. Jenkins version 2.168.
3. Jenkins Installed via `yum install jenkins`

I hope this will help some one.