# TestBench license and Jenkins on AWS

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, jenkins, vaadin, test-bench

I've setup several headless UI tests using Vaadin TestBench but Jenkins fails due to licensing when running:

```
License for Vaadin TestBench 4 not found. Go to vaadin.com/pro for more details.
```

The Vaadin documentation states to put the license file in the home directory, specifically stating `/Users/<home>` but that isn't a valid location for a RHEL EC2 instance.

I have tried placing my license file in `/home/<user>` and `/home/<user>/` and even tried creating the `/Users/` directory in case it is hardcoded to only check that location.

I've tried modifying the Jenkins Maven job to add the following into MAVEN_OPTS:

```
-Dvaadin.testbench.developer.license=<LICENSE>
```

So far it always fails to find my license when running the test jobs.

What is the correct way to add licenses that Jenkins can access running on an AWS EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the license as a java property, I guess in jenkens it's done in another way.
[System properties management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539234/system-properties-management)

Answer (score 0):

Build settings in the Goals and options field 
`-Dvaadin.testbench.developer.license=<LICENSE>`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the user context that Jenkins was running in.  While I assumed that it was under the default user it was actually running as another, so that the license needed to be in a different home directory to be detected.

However, this still fails to explain why the Java -D switch failed to load the license.  Maybe an issue here with Maven jobs on Jenkins passing arguments to TestBench?