# Jenkins email plugin doesn't send email to user who broke the build

Tags: email, jenkins

I've setup Jenkins to send emails only to users who broke the build using email-ext plugin, but I'm getting this error:

> Not sending mail to unregistered user user@example.com because your SCM claimed this was associated with a user ID ‘John Smith' which your security realm does not recognize; you may need changes in your SCM plugin

I don't really understand what this error means, is the problem in our SCM, or in the email plugin? The emails are taken from the commit history, should I register them somewhere so Jenkins will start working?

For reference, [this is the code around the error message](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/recipients/RecipientProviderUtilities.java#L209) in the plugin's source code:

```
                    } catch (UsernameNotFoundException x) {
                        if (SEND_TO_UNKNOWN_USERS) {
                            listener.getLogger().printf("Warning: %s is not a recognized user, but sending mail anyway%n", userAddress);
                        } else {
                            listener.getLogger().printf("Not sending mail to unregistered user %s because your SCM"
                    ........
```

How do I enable `SEND_TO_UNKNOWN_USERS`?

The error message is also mentioned in this [bug report](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43268).

Comment: `static /* not final */ boolean SEND_TO_UNKNOWN_USERS = Boolean.getBoolean(MailSender.class.getName() + ".SEND_TO_UNKNOWN_USERS");
`

So... just figure out how to set that boolean since you have the sourcecode?

Comment: @Shark I have it for reference, I don't compile it from source. I need to set it from configuration somehow.

Comment: `-Dhudson.tasks.MailSender.SEND_TO_UNKNOWN_USERS=true` perhaps ? as read [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) on the `email-ext` plugin wiki

Comment: Can this be set from the web interface? I tried setting it from Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Properties -> Environment Variables, but nothing happened.

Comment: Looks like the Email Extension plugin adds a checkbox to the system configuration: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For version V2.61 or above this can be configured via a radio button.

Go to

> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Extended E-mail Notification

and tick the radio button for **Allow sending to unregistered users**

[image]

**Edit:** If this does not work, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45353810/492336 for another solution.

Comment: Also you can set "Allowed Domains" to your company domains for example: @mycompany.com for security reasons

Comment: "Allow sending to unregistered users" and "Allowed Domains" don't work in Jenkins ver. 2.164.1.

Comment: "Allow sending to unregistered users" also didn't work in Jenkins ver. 2.198

Comment: Hm, I was thinking about accepting this answer since it's the most upvoted, but the above 2 comments make me unsure about it. Does it work for everyone or not?

Answer (score 20):

OK, after some experiments this is what I found out:

Jenkins takes the email part of the committer (not the author). For example for a commit message that looks like that:

```
Author: John Smith <author1@example1.com>  2017-07-27 17:15:39
Committer: John Doe <committer1@example2.com>  2017-07-27 17:15:39
Parent: 9c3ff18dda8ca6f7b7ac4ebab4c76d3c85891a33 (commit)
Branch: master
```

Jenkins will take "committer1", and create a brand new user under People with User ID "committer1" and email "". Unless that user has a password however, it will be considered unregistered so you need to go to Configure for that user and add a password field to it:

[image]

So this is one way to fix the error, but you have to do it for every user and in a big team it can be tedious.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer because it's better than disabling security.

Comment: This is not possible when using ldap and I assume active directory

Comment: hi, what do you mean add a password field for it? I can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 9):

Put the line bellow in your jenkins startup script

```
-Dhudson.tasks.MailSender.SEND_TO_UNKNOWN_USERS=true
```

The newest Jenkins security directive only allow sending mail to registered user. The line above bypass this configuration.

Comment: How does Jenkins decide whether a user is registered? Does it check if the Author Name from SCM is the same as the User ID (as opposed to User Name) of an existing user?

Comment: Yes. If the committer names is joao.vitorino and there is a user with login joao.vitorino and email address configured, jenkins do the match and send the email. You can solve by adding the config I posted or configuring the user in jenkins

Comment: You can also use configure Jenkins to use ActiveDirectory or LDAP to identify your development users, so you do not need to configure each user individually in Jenkins.

Comment: Or put to [jenkins.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539234/system-properties-management/40256264#40256264). There are [SEND_TO_USERS_WITHOUT_READ and SEND_TO_UNKNOWN_USERS](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Given jenkins takes the first part of the email address and creates a user, I made my team have their jenkins user name be the first part of their email address. This removed any overhead of having to maintain two separate users.