# you may need changes in your SCM plugin An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored error in Jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting the following error in Jenkins while trying to trigger mails using emailext in jenkins pipeline.
Not sending mail to unregistered user abc@xyz.com because your SCM claimed this was associated with a user ID ‘abc' which your security realm does not recognize; you may need changes in your SCM plugin An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.

Comment: probably a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350740/jenkins-email-plugin-doesnt-send-email-to-user-who-broke-the-build

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins email plugin doesn't send email to user who broke the build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350740/jenkins-email-plugin-doesnt-send-email-to-user-who-broke-the-build)