# Content Security Policy violation on code review HTML

Tags: code-coverage, content-security-policy

I am generating code coverage for my rust project and am trying to publish the results to Jenkins using `publishHTML`.  All good except that when I try to view the HTML the CSS does not load because of this error:

`Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

How do I fix this? I doubt I'm the first person to run into this.

I did have the thought to rewrite the generated HTML to use a local stylesheet, but I ran into weird Access permissions in the Jenkins workspace and I could not get that to work.

This is the command I am using the generate the reports:

`grcov . --binary-path workspaces -s . -t html --branch --ignore-not-existing -o ./code_coverage/`

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this or how to better deploy my results.

Comment: Stylesheets and probably most other resources are only allowed to load from the same domain/port that your webserver serves the pages from. Don't use a CDN then; instead download the external resources and deploy them on your webserver as static assets.

Answer (score 0):

Default [CSP header in Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/configuring-content-security-policy/#the-default-rule-set) is:

```
sandbox; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';
```

so you have to add `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/` (or `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net`) into `style-src` directive.

You can use [post initialization script (init hook)](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/groovy-hook-scripts/#post-initialization-script-init-hook) to run some additional things right after Jenkins starts up. Create a file, such as `$JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/adjust-content-security-policy.groovy` (or any *.groovy* file in `$JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/` directory) with the single line of:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox; default-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/")
```

and it will be executed after Jenkins has started.

Pls note a *Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback* in the violation message. This means that default Jenkins CSP was changed and `style-src` directive is absent. So check files in the `$JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/` directory maybe you already have one with CSP settings.
Safiest way is to see in the browser console what CSP header you do have, to add `style-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/"` into it and then set resulting CSP into `System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "...")`. Perhaps the Jenkins documentation just is behind the times.

> 

There is a way of use [jenkins.xml](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/windows-service/jenkins.xml) file if you run Jenkins on Windows. Add the property:

```
-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="sandbox; default-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/"
```

in `<service><arguments>` before the `-jar`, than restart the service. See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618892/jenkins-content-security-policy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539234/system-properties-management/40256264#40256264).